# Non-pathological example where Newton's method converges to a saddle point or local maximum

Tags: optimization, numerical-methods, nonlinear-optimization, numerical-optimization, newton-raphson

It is well known that Newton's method (with full step size) may converge to a saddle point or local maximum for some initial values (assuming it converges to something), but I have trouble visualizing it. I am always under the impression that such initial values have measure zero in the domain, because if you perturb the solution a little bit, it will have a non-zero gradient and can thus escape to somewhere with a lower value.

Can someone provide a non-pathological example where Newton's method does not converge to a local minimum, where "pathological" means the set of initial values leading to a saddle point or local maximum (i.e. basin of attraction) has measure zero? Preferably the example should also be simple so that it's easier to visualize it.

Comment: Just take any function that Newtons method would converge to a minima, and flip it upside down. Now Newtons method will converge to a maxima. Negative eigenvalues of the hessian flip the direction of the gradient

Comment: In the basic implementation of  Newton's method for optimization, there is no guarantee that the function is even decreasing as the iteration progresses. The only thing that matters is  that the norm of the gradient decreases. The phrase "escape to somewhere with  a lower value" has no meaning in Newton's method as  the function's value is not used. All that matters is how close your iteration is to a root of the gradient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For converging to a maximum, Nick Alger provided an answer in their comment

> Just take any function that Newton's method would converge to a minimum, and flip it upside down. Now Newton's method will converge to a maximum. Negative eigenvalues of the hessian flip the direction of the gradient.

For converging to a saddle point, consider $f(x) = x^3$ and any initial value. The update is

\begin{equation}
x_{k+1} = x_k - \frac{f'(x_k)}{f''(x_k)} = x_k - \frac{3x_k^2}{6x_k} = \frac{1}{2} x_k
\end{equation}

As a result, the algorithm will converge to the saddle point $x = 0$ regardless of the initialization.